# Передача аргумента типа-перечисления в метод на C#

Tags: c#, enum

Как сделать что-то типа класса идентификатора?
Я даже не знаю как правильно это назвать и класс ли это вообще.

Проблема такая. Пишу логи для программы. Логи бывают 2 типов: сообщение и ошибка.
Есть метод, который нужно вызвать и передать туда информацию о том сообщение ли это или ошибка.

```
public void Log(LogType type)
{

}
```

Проблема заключается именно в LogType. Я не знаю как его правильно реализовать, чтобы можно было при передаче сделать следующее:

```
Log(LogType.Error);
```

или

```
Log(LogType.Message);
```

Заранее спасибо.
Передача через переменную int 0-сообщение 1-ошибка и т.п. не катит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [перечисление `enum`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum):

```
public enum LogType
{
    Message, Error
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, работает.

Answer (score 3):

Вам подойдет вариант с `enum`

```
public enum LogType
{
    Error = 0,
    Message = 1
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.